# Using Watir to click on a specific link when there are other links with the same display text

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, automated-tests

[image]

so i have a table that looks something like that where there is a list of books and in the very first column there is two links, view and delete, for each book.

i would like to be able to use Watir to find the row with a specified book title and click on that view button for that book.

Here is what I have so far

```
And /^click on View link of "(.*)" on the result set table$/ do |cell_name|
   cellButton("submit.view", cell_name, "")
end
#
#
And /^click on Delete link of "(.*)" on the result set table with no_wait$/ do |cell_name|
   cellButton("submit.delete", cell_name, "no_wait")
end
#
#
def cellButton(submit_type, s_name, s_wait_type)
   c_found = 0
      @browser.tables do |tbl|
         tbl.rows do |r|
            r.each do |c|
               if c.text.to_s.matches(s_name)
                   c_found += 1
                end
               break if c_found > 0
            end
            if c_found > 0
               if s_wait_type == "no_wait"
                  r.button(:name, submit_type).click_no_wait
               else
                  r.button(:name, submit_type).click
               end
            end
            break if c_found > 0
         end
      end
end
```

and here is the html for a specific view button

```
<tr class="even">
     <td class="actionColumn">
         <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;">[</span>
         <input id="013c6e2c8187_885b_1bd1f6fc" name="submit.view" class="action_link" size="" value="View" type="button"  onclick="location.href='book_details.html'">
         <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;">]</span><br>                                                 
         <div>
             <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;">[</span>
             <input id="013c6e2c8187_1194_75ae28a8" name="submit.delete" class="action_link" size="" value="Delete" type="button">
             <span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: inline;">]</span>                                                  
         </div>
     </td>
     <td>
        book title
     <td>
     <td>
        more tds
     </td>
 </tr>
```

there is no error when the script is run, however, the view link is not pressed.

i am using Watir 4.0, Ruby 1.9.3 and Cucumber 1.3.3

Comment: A couple of observations: 1) I believe the `click_no_wait` method is deprecated (if I'm not mistaken); and 2) there's an `onclick` attribute on the button, which means you may have to use the [`fire_event`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#fire_event-instance_method) method.

Comment: When giving the html example of what you are working with, it is important to give all of the related html. Giving us the "link" is good since we can see it is actually a button that looks like a link. However, we do not know what the rest of the table looks like (ie how does the book title relate back to the button).

Comment: i added more html code i haven't had a chance to look at your answers yet. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your table html is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="013c6e2c8187_885b_1bd1f6fc" name="submit.view" class="action_link" size value="View" type="button" onclick="location.href='book_details.html'"> 
        </td>
        <td>
            book title 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="013c6e2c8122_885b_1bd1f6fc" name="submit.view" class="action_link" size value="View" type="button" onclick="location.href='book_details2.html'"> 
        </td>
        <td>
            book title 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can see that the book title and view button are related by their parent row (tr).

The easiest way to access an element by its sibling is to:

1. Find the element with the unique attribute; in this case the td with the book title.
2. Get the parent element (ie the tr) using the `parent` method.
3. Get the desired element in relation to the parent element (ie first view button in the row).

For example, to get the View button for 'book title 2', you can do:

```
book_title = 'book title 2'
table = browser.table(:id => 'my_table')
book_row = table.td(:text => book_title).parent
book_row.button(:value => 'View').click
```

The above solution will look for the book title in any column. This is fine if the book title text is only expected to be in the one column. If it is possible that the text will be in another column, you will want to do:

```
book_title = 'book title 2'
table = browser.table(:id => 'my_table')
book_row = table.trs.find{ |tr| tr.td(:index => 1).text == book_title }
book_row.button(:value => 'View').click
```

Comment: i actually can't search table by id because a similar table can be on a different page with a different id, but my script would still need to be usable with that. but that's not your fault it was my fault for being unclear. i ended up just putting your code in a @browser.tables.each do |table| loop. and altering your code accordingly. but i am amazed that you managed to do what i needed in 4 lines...verus my  many lines. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There's likely a cleaner way, but I'll give it a shot.

Assuming this simplified HTML (i.e. 2-column table with links instead of buttons):

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr><td><a href="http://www.example.com">View</a></td><td>Title One</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved">View</a></td><td>Title Two</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="http://www.iana.org/numbers">View</a></td><td>Title Three</td></tr>
</table>
```

This code should work by targeting the book title:

```
title = "Title Three"

trs = b.table(:id => "foo").rows
row_index = 0
trs.each do |tr|
  tr.each do |cell|
    if cell.text == title
      b.link(:text => "View", :index => "#{row_index}").click
      # alternately, using the fire_event method
      # b.link(:text => "View", :index => "#{row_index}").fire_event("onclick")
    end    
  end
  row_index += 1  
end
```

Comment: this is way cleaner than what i had but Justin's answer was way less code and more efficient. thanks for your contribution though. and i did take some of your other suggestions bout the deprecated click_no_wait

Comment: @livelaughlove: that's the beauty of SO.  Everyone contributes, and the community determines what's best.  Glad I could be of some help.