# For a unique specified value in table column 2, how do I click column 8 in the same row?

Tags: watir

In a table, the user looks for a unique value in column 2, and clicks whatever is in column 8. This opens a popup form.

I know how to use Watir to click in col 8. But I don't know how to click col 8 for a specified value in col 2. I don't care what's in col 8.

Here are the debug statements:

```
table = browser.table(:id => 'ManageLists')
row_2 = table[1]
cell_2 = row_2[1]
debug cell_2.text     # ad.05.IL.R.nC.Own.Wait
cell_8 = row_2[7]
debug cell_8.text     # 7   (Just coincidence. It could be any number)
```

Here's how to click on cell 8:

```
browser.span(:text => "7").click
```

HTML for cell 2:

```
<span onclick="javascript:showListMembers(353);" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;">ad.05.IL.R.nC.Own.Wait</span>
```

HTML for cell 8:

```
<span onclick="javascript:showListMembers(353);" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;">7</span>
```

So, to repeat the scenario:  I want Watir to look for `ad.05.IL.R.nC.Own.Wait` then click on column 8.

## ------------------------------------

HTML added. Only columns 2 and 8 are expanded. Note that the code is for the second row, not the first. Because I suspect that some of my attempts to click column 8 succeeded only because they were in the first row. So specifying a lower row always selected col 8 in the first row.

```
<table id="ManageLists" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"     tabindex="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_ManageLists" style="width: 1015px;">
<tbody>
<tr class="jqgfirstrow" style="height:auto" role="row">
<tr id="1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">
<tr id="2" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" tabindex="-1" role="row">

<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_Id" title="351" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">351</td>

<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_ListName" title="ad.05.IL.nR.nC.Own.Wait" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">
<span onclick="javascript:showListMembers(351);" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;">ad.05.IL.nR.nC.Own.Wait</span></td>

<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_List Owner" title="xxxxxx, xxxxx" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">
<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_List Type" title="iList" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">iList</td>
<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_Status" title="Waiting" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">Waiting</td>
<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_Restricted" title="No" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">No</td>
<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_Confidential" title="No" style="text-align:left;" role="gridcell">No</td>

<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_Members" title="7" style="text-align:right!important;" role="gridcell">
<span onclick="javascript:showListMembers(351);" style="text-decoration:none; border-bottom: 1px solid Gray;">7</span></td>

<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_Nominees Waiting" title="0" style="text-align:right!important;" role="gridcell">0</td>
<td aria-describedby="ManageLists_Audit" title="" style="text-align:center !important;" role="gridcell">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
table = browser.table(:id => 'ManageLists')
row = table.trs.find { |tr| tr[1].text == 'ad.05.IL.R.nC.Own.Wait' }
row.td(:index => 7).span.click
```

Description:

- The first line gets the table to search.
- The second line goes through the rows and finds the first row where the text in the second column is 'ad.05.IL.R.nC.Own.Wait'.
- The third line takes the row found and clicks the span in the eighth column.

Comment: Got errror: `Failure/Error: row.td(:index => 7).span.click
NoMethodError: undefined method 'td' for nil:NilClass` Because I'm dealing with siblings, I'm experimenting with "parent", as in xPath. No luck so far.

Comment: ...as in your post `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581687/using-watir-to-click-on-a-specific-link-when-there-are-other-links-with-the-same` where the column 2 value is unique.

Comment: Can you please give the html of your table?

Comment: Appended to my original question.

Comment: The code seems to work fine as long as you are trying to find the right text. The code in this answer used the text seen in the originally provided span, which was "ad.05.IL.R.nC.Own.Wait". In contrast, the updated table has the text of "ad.05.IL.nR.nC.Own.Wait". Updating the string in this code or that in your application should address the issue.

Comment: Apologies. Your code works with any row. (The first search term that I provided is for the first row. The second search term that I provided in the long code extract is for the second row, because my experiments ALWAYS clicked the first row - even although the search term was for some other row.) I can't reproduce the error message that I quoted above.

Comment: I'm marking Justin's answer as correct, because marking my own "alternative" answer would be gross rudeness. Anyway, my own answer is based on one of Jutin's old posts.

Comment: If you went with the "parent" approach that you posted, it is perfectly reasonable to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've cracked the "parent" problem. As mentioned elsewhere in this thread, the solution is based on one of Justin's old posts here:

[Using Watir to click on a specific link when there are other links with the same display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581687/using-watir-to-click-on-a-specific-)‌​link-when-there-are-other-links-with-the-same

I'm comfortable with "parent", because I was quite good at xPath with Selenium. The idea is to find the common ancestor of cell 2 and cell 8.  The trick is understanding that the number of intervening ancestors does not need to be the same for cell 2 as it is for cell 8. And the intervening tags can be different. (In my specific case, everything IS the same. Can't lose them all.)

The Watir "parent" seems to be much easier to code than xPath.

In my scenario, tr is the nearest common ancestor of cell 2 and cell 8. The structure to tr from cell 2 is:

```
<tr
  <td
    <span
```

So, my final code is:

```
# span = browser.span(:text => "ad.05.IL.R.nC.Own.Wait")   # first row. Works OK
# span = browser.span(:text => "ad.05.IL.nR.nC.Own.Wait")   # second row. Works OK
span = browser.span(:text => "ad.03.IL.R.nC.nOwn.Wait")   # ninth row. Works OK
td = span.parent
tr = td.parent    
tr.td(:index => 7).span.click     # click cell 8 in the specified row
```

You can see that the down path from tr to cell 8 is identical to the up path from cell 2 to tr.  But that's just a coincidence.